# Как выполнить действие , если условие совпадает с любым одним названием массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```js
    let ask = (prompt("Enter your browser " , ''));
    let browser = ['Edge','Chrome','Firefox','Safari','Opera'] ;
    
    if (? // выполнить если ask равен любому одному названию массива browser ) {
     ...
    }
```

Comment: [browser.includes(ask)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    let ask = (prompt("Enter your browser " , ''));
    let browser = ['Edge','Chrome','Firefox','Safari','Opera'] ;

    browser.forEach(function (a) {
        if (ask == a){
            console.log('Найдено совпадение, выполнить функцию');
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно строго оставить if, по заданию:

```
let ask = (prompt("Enter your browser " , ''));
let browser = ['Edge','Chrome','Firefox','Safari','Opera'] ;

if (ask && browser.contains(ask) ) {
 ...
}
```